# Subtract two days and calculate working days only (no Saturdays or Sundays)

Tags: java, date

I am looking for an external JAR or a method that will supply me the following abilities:

1. Subtract two dates.
2. Define holidays as Saturday and Sunday, or Friday and Saturday.
3. Calculate the difference with holidays or without them.

Can anyone recommend an external JAR before I go into Gregorian calendar calculations?

Comment: Have you tried using the [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class?

Comment: i take it you're working in milliseconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look [at this site](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/5734/calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-ignoring-weekends/), they provide you a java program that helps you with that:

> The wdnum() method returns the number of weekdays (excluding weekends) that have passed since Monday, 29 December 1969. It works by calculating the number of days since 1 January, 1970 (getTime() divided by the number of milliseconds in a day), adding 3 and returning the number of week days in full weeks and possibly a partial week that have passed since then.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/index.html) it may be helpful with what you're trying to do.

However, more than likely you're going to have to use the methods in the Calendar class such as getTimeInMillis() to subtract the dates and fields in the Calendar class such as Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK or Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH to determine the day of the week if you want to exclude certain days of the week from your calculations.